# Inserting already deflated files in a zip file

Tags: java, android, performance, zip, compression

I have been searching for this issue but I cannot find any response that I can use.

Is it possible (using **java**) to include **new files** that are **already deflated** in a **zip file** in a way that, after, when I **decompress** the zip file, those deflated files are **inflated in the same way as if they were passed "inflated"** to the zip tool and incorporated to the zip as to be compressed ("DEFLETED" in the ZipEntry according to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html#setMethod-int-). In that case, how?

Most of the information about compression with java for zip files I get from google and others searchers can be resumed in:

- Opening the zip as a file system https://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2011/08/java-7-working-with-zip-files.html
- Using streams directly (https://www.java-examples.com/create-zip-file-using-zipoutputstream-example)

I deflect the files using JZlib (but you can do with whatever any other library. An example, http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-deflate-and-inflate-a-file.html)

As you can expect about what I said, when I try to insert the already deflated files, they are deflated again (using the DEFLETED method in the ZipEntry, that is the default) and when the zip file is unzipped, the files are deflated to the their former already deflated state.

Looking to the source of ZipOutputStream.java from oracle, you can see that there are two methods for adding entries to the zip:

```
    DEFLATED (an integer set to 20)
    STORED   (an integer set to 10)
```

**What I want is to add the deflated entries as STORED in the zip, but once they are added, to change the info in the own zip as if they were processed DEFLATED**. Do you know any library or any alternative to do it easily? I was thinking in making my own ZipOutputStream inheriting from the jdk ZipOutputStream and overriding the methods to make the trick, but a "fast copy-paste and modification" of the methods according to this idea -just to have a "it could work" feeling- did not work according to my hopes either.

The reason why I would like to have this option is to compress huge amount of files in a zip file on demand dynamically. **I am not sure if this could save time and cpu having the deflated files saved in the database** and selecting in each moment those files that are requested to make the zips.

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Hi Guillermo, did you notice my solution from Sep 6 2020 at 20:42 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an outdated thread but looking in to my old folders for cleaning up the disk, I saw a "draft" project I made with this idea for my job. Finally, we discarded it but I have uploaded it to a repo if somebody could be interested in it...

https://gitlab.com/gylz.mail/dynazip

It is not even a prototype, just a short example program for showing how this would work. As Mark Alder said, the zip format is not complicated and it is well explained in the link he pointed out in his response.

Answer (score 1):

The zip format is not terribly complicated, so you should just take the deflated data and write your own zip file headers around it. The format is documented [here](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT). If you are deriving the deflated data from gzip files, then you also should already have the CRCs and uncompressed lengths. (If each gzip file you want to convert consists of a single deflate stream, i.e. is one gzip member, and if the uncompressed lengths are assured to be less than 2<sup>32</sup> bytes, then you can delete the "should" in that statement.)

Comment: I have been "playing" with it (see my solution below) and got a draft experimental approach. I was wondering about the possibility that jdk had comtemplated the scenario I asked for so there would be and "easy" and compact way of getting it (i.e just indicating a "special" method in the configuration of the ZipOutputSream, or adding or changing few sentences regarding to the snippet of code that normally are shown as examples for compressing plain files)

Answer (score 0):

I could imagine a hack.... between `putNextEntry(e)` and `write`, you could possible use `e.setMethod`. The code like like it writes the header at the end of `putNextEntry` and decides about compression in `write` where it accesses the very entry it's been given in `putNextEntry` (no copy is made).

You may need to flip it back before calling `closeEntry`.

I didn't try it as you can try it much faster.

---

> I am not sure if this could save time and cpu having the deflated files saved in the database

I'm not getting it, but I'm very skeptical.

OTOH your idea looks applicable also when given a bunch of `*.gz` files, you want to store their plaintext without decompressing and compressing them again.

Comment: Avoiding compression and decompression as much as possible is the target. Think in a huge repository which only function is to serve large sets of compressed data from which the users can build their own (big) databases.  Compress once and use then as many time as needed for buiding dinamically customized bundles of data and databases on demand can save memory and processing. The flows of compressed data are shorter and the time to process them is reduced.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I went further from my first approch, analyzed the jdk source deeper and spent some time debugging and modifying it:

https://gist.github.com/gylz/b2db94ce55f1829f2e2a2cd498092d46

https://gist.github.com/gylz/284d8b891fc0bbd3161d1ec5929be074

If you want to try it, you have to indicate the paths you want in the variables PATH_ZIP_DIR, PATH_IN_DIR, PATH_TMP_DIR in the Test class. The files to compress are taken from the PATH_IN_DIR directoy and the zip file created in PATH_ZIP_DIR. The test class is short and not too complicated (despite of being a draft as the ExtraZipOutputStream class too). I used simple text files in PATH_IN_DIR to test their compression. As you can see, in this class, the deflate() method is the one that performs the deflaton before compress() put the files in zip file (thanks to the modified ExtraZipOutputStream, using STORED but writing the metadata associated to the files as if they had been deflated by ExtraZipOutputStream itself.)

In the comment block appended to the header of ExtraZipOutputStream.class, I explain how to detect the changes I have made to the original code.

Answer (score 0):

I took a little look at ZipOutputStream & came up with this.

I've created 2 Classes: `PreparedZipEntryBuilder` & `PreparedZipEntry`.

This will create the shortest possibly ZipEntry for a given sequence of bytes.

In PreparedZipEntryBuilder I've included a number of Test Cases.

It's completely non-invasive, quite simple & commented throughout.

Have fun.

Here's PreparedZipEntry:

```
package com.stackoverflow.preparedzipentry;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.CRC32;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class PreparedZipEntry {

    private final int    originalLength;
    private final long   originalCRC;
    private final int    deflatedLength;
    private final int    bestMethodDeterminedByBuilder;
    private final byte[] preparedEntryBytes;
    private final long   preparedEntryBytesCRC;
    
    /* package private */ PreparedZipEntry(final int originalLength, final long originalCRC, final int deflatedLength, final int method, final byte[] preparedEntryBytes) {

        final CRC32 preparedEntryBytesCRC32 = new CRC32();
        /**/        preparedEntryBytesCRC32.update(preparedEntryBytes);

        /*
         * These 6 Fields are all you need to correctly insert a prepared entry.
         * If desired, they can be written to a File for later use.
         * (in that case you might want to pass the original bytes to this constructor too?)
         */
        this.originalLength                = originalLength;
        this.originalCRC                   = originalCRC;
        this.deflatedLength                = deflatedLength;
        this.bestMethodDeterminedByBuilder = method;
        this.preparedEntryBytes            = preparedEntryBytes;
        this.preparedEntryBytesCRC         = preparedEntryBytesCRC32.getValue();
    }

    /**
     * Writes our PreparedZipEntry to the Outputstream.
     * <p>
     * You may set the FileTimes in the returned ZipEntry.<br>
     * LastModifiedTime will be used to create the Zip-Directory @ EOF
     * 
     * @param   zos
     * @param   entryName
     * @return
     * @throws  IOException
     */
    public ZipEntry writeEntry(final ZipOutputStream zos, final String entryName) throws IOException {

        final ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(entryName);

        /*
         * Set the Sizes correctly for the Entry Header & write an Entry for the desired Method...
         */
        entry.setSize          (this.originalLength);
        entry.setCompressedSize(this.deflatedLength);
        entry.setCrc           (this.originalCRC);
        entry.setMethod        (this.bestMethodDeterminedByBuilder);  // Must use this Method (influences LOC-Header construction)
        zos.putNextEntry(entry);

        /*
         * Now set the byte-count to what write(...) is expecting for the prepared bytes and write them as STORED...
         */
        entry.setMethod(ZipEntry.STORED);
        entry.setSize  (this.preparedEntryBytes.length);
        zos.write      (this.preparedEntryBytes);

        /*
         * Now set the CRC to what closeEntry() is expecting for the bytes just STORED & close the Entry...
         */
        entry.setCrc   (this.preparedEntryBytesCRC);
        zos.closeEntry();

        /*
         * Finally, set the Sizes, CRC & Method correctly once more...
         * (ZipOutputStream will use these later to write the Zip-Directory @ EOF)
         */
        entry.setSize  (this.originalLength);
        entry.setCrc   (this.originalCRC);
        entry.setMethod(this.bestMethodDeterminedByBuilder);

        return entry;
    }
}
```

And here's the Builder:

```
package com.stackoverflow.preparedzipentry;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.UncheckedIOException;

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
import java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime;

import java.time.Instant;

import java.util.zip.CRC32;
import java.util.zip.Deflater;
import java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class PreparedZipEntryBuilder {

    public static PreparedZipEntry of(final byte[] entryBytes) {

        final int    entryBytesLength    = entryBytes.length;
        final long   entryBytesCRC       = getCRC32(entryBytes);

        final byte[] deflatedBytes       = getDeflatedBytes(entryBytes);
        final int    deflatedBytesLength = deflatedBytes.length;

        /*
         * Depending on how well the bytes compress, generate an uncompressed or compressed PreparedZipEntry...
         */
        if (deflatedBytesLength < entryBytesLength) {
            /*
             * Compressed length was less than the uncompressed length
             */
            return new PreparedZipEntry(entryBytesLength, entryBytesCRC, deflatedBytesLength, ZipEntry.DEFLATED, deflatedBytes);
        } else {
            return new PreparedZipEntry(entryBytesLength, entryBytesCRC, entryBytesLength,    ZipEntry.STORED,   entryBytes);
            /*
             * Uncompressed was shorter!
             */
        }
    }

    private static byte[] getDeflatedBytes(final byte[] bytes) {

        try(final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream((int) (bytes.length * 0.4 /* Guess: 40% */));
            final          OutputStream bos  = new  BufferedOutputStream(baos);
            final  DeflaterOutputStream dos  = new  DeflaterOutputStream(bos, new Deflater(Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION, true)))
        {
            dos.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            dos.close();

            return baos.toByteArray();
        }
        catch (final           IOException cannotHappen) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(cannotHappen);
        }
    }

    private static long getCRC32(final byte[] bytes) {

        final CRC32 crc32 = new CRC32();
        /**/        crc32.update(bytes);
        return      crc32.getValue();
    }

    private static ZipEntry writeRegularEntryUnknown(final ZipOutputStream zos, final String entryName, final byte[] entryBytes) throws IOException {

        final byte[] deflatedBytes       = getDeflatedBytes(entryBytes);

        final ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(entryName);
        /**/           entry.setLastModifiedTime(FileTime.from(Instant.now())); // For test: not absolutely necessary.

        entry.setSize          (entryBytes   .length);
        entry.setCompressedSize(deflatedBytes.length);
        entry.setCrc           (getCRC32(entryBytes));
        entry.setMethod        (ZipEntry.DEFLATED);

        zos.putNextEntry(entry);
        zos.write       (entryBytes, 0, entryBytes.length);
        zos.closeEntry();

        return entry;
    }

    private static ZipEntry writeRegularEntryKnown(final ZipOutputStream zos, final String entryName, final byte[] entryBytes) throws IOException {

        final ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(entryName);
        /**/           entry.setLastModifiedTime(FileTime.from(Instant.now())); // For test: not absolutely necessary.
        /**/           entry.setMethod        (ZipEntry.DEFLATED);

        zos.putNextEntry(entry);
        zos.write       (entryBytes, 0, entryBytes.length);
        zos.closeEntry();

        return entry;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final ZipOutputStream        zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
        /**/                         zos.setLevel(Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION);

        final String string0s = ">00000000<";
        final String string09 = "0123456789";
        final String stringaz = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        final String stringAZ = stringaz.toUpperCase();

        int z = 1000;

        for (final String entryText : new String[] {
                "Short",
                "Compresses poorly : "    + string09 + stringaz + stringAZ,
                "Compresses well : "      + string09 + string09 + string09 + string09 + string09 + string09,
                "Compresses very well : " + string0s + string0s + string0s + string0s + string0s + string0s,
                "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------", // <- Compresses extremely well
        }) {
            for (final String ab : new String[] {"a", "b"}) {

                final PreparedZipEntry prepared =  PreparedZipEntryBuilder.of(entryText.getBytes());
                /**/                   prepared.writeEntry     (zos, z++ + ab + "_Prepared");
                /**/                   writeRegularEntryKnown  (zos, z++ + ab + "_Regular_KnownLength",   entryText.getBytes());
                final ZipEntry  last = writeRegularEntryUnknown(zos, z++ + ab + "_Regular_unknownLength", entryText.getBytes());
                /**/            last.setLastModifiedTime(FileTime.from(Instant.now().minusSeconds(99 * z)));
            }
        }

        zos.close();

        final byte[] mainBytes = baos.toByteArray();

        final Path path = Paths.get("MultiMemberPredeflated.zip");

        Files.deleteIfExists(path);
        Files.write         (path, mainBytes, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
    }
}
```